# Variable set on true looses value after first if-statement ---?

Tags: php, debugging, if-statement, boolean

This seems very bizarre to me. 
At the beginning of my php-script I am defining a debug variable. In the script I am using this variable to test my functions etc. p.p. BUT:
After my first if-Statement, the variable $debug is not set on true but blank... what am I doing wrong:
Here is my code:

```
$debug=true;

if($debug){
    echo 'Testausgabe: </br></br>';
    include 'jsonData.php';
    include 'database.php'; 
    $ini_config=$ini_config = parse_ini_file("config.ini", true);
    echo "Einbindung erfolgt!".LNBR;
    $debug=true;
    echo $debug;
    echo LNBR;
}



function dropdownGen($link,$ini_config){
    $drops=$ini_config['dropDowns'];
    foreach($drops as $key => $liste){
        $data=json_liste($link,$liste);
        echo    LNBR;
        echo    "droplist_parse=JSON.parse('".$data."');";
        echo    "ddslickNoImage(droplist_parse,'".$liste."');";
        echo    LNBR;
        echo    "ddslickNoImage_Toggle(droplist_parse,'".$liste."');";
        echo    LNBR;
    }
}

function dropdownImgGen($link, $ini_config){
    $images=$ini_config['image_links'];
    print_r($images);
    echo "<br><br>";
    foreach($images as $key => $liste){
        $link='..\\'.utf8_decode($liste);
        echo $link;
        echo LNBR;
        $data=json_imageList($link);
        echo $data;
        echo LNBR;
        echo "ddslickImageList(".$data.",'".$key."');";
    }

}

if($debug){
    echo $debug;
    echo LNBR;
    echo 'Testausgabe: </br></br>';
    dropdownGen($link,$ini_config);
    echo LNBR;
    dropdownImgGen($link,$ini_config);
    echo LNBR;
}
```

Comment: `echo true;` gives `1` perhaps you're just missing that as it is prepended to the `LNBR` value?

Comment: Is there anything in the `jsonData.php` or `database.php` scripts which may change it?

Comment: Usually debug flags are defined as constants, this way they have global scope, they cannot change their value etc.

Comment: Well ... the LNBR value is just a Linebreak Constant ... I am using it more than once thats Why it is defined in database as a constant....

Comment: I don´t use a constant here, because I have a debug in every script and want to set it individually...

Comment: I think database.php and jsonData.php are the point. I am using the same debug variable in each script... so .... I define an individual variable for each script... that was the point ... now it works thanks @NigelRen°